# SED: Search a alphanumeric string and replace it

Tags: bash, sed

I need to search and replace an alphanumeric string using SED.

Search String: `Test:rXXXXX`, where XXXXX will always be a 5 digit number

Replace String: `Test:rYYYYY`, where YYYYY will always be a 5 digit number

I have come up with the following :

```
echo 'Test:r12345' | sed 's/Test:r[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/Test:rYYYYY/g'
```

This works currently.

Is there a better way to achieve this? I don't want to  use '[0-9]' 5 times in the expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another one with sed with a small modification to match the "Test:r" subexpression making the replacement a bit more terse

```
echo 'Test:r12345' | sed 's/\(Test:r\)[0-9]\{5\}/\1YYYYY/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this syntax instead:

```
[0-9]{5}
```

This requires you to pass '-r' to sed, so the new example will be:

```
echo 'Test:r12345' | sed -r 's/Test:r[0-9]{5}$/Test:rYYYYY/g'
```

Comment: It would be better to point that sed/awk/grep use POSIX regular expressions and why the additional `-r` is required. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Syntax

Comment: Also, the -r is not strictly necessary, but it changes the syntax somewhat if it is omitted: sed 's/Test:r[0-9]\{5\}/...'

Comment: Thanks guys,                                                        Any idea why sed -i 's/Test:r[0-9]\{5\}$/Test:rYYYYY/g' myfile.txt wouldnt work? Is the syntax wrong

Answer (score 1):

well, based on your sample, you can just replace the 2nd field using `awk`

```
echo 'Test:r12345' | awk -F":" '{$2="rYYYYY"}1' OFS=":"
```

There is no need to create complex regular expression. KISS